# Get the values from the vertical slider in pyqt4 and save that value into one variable

Tags: python, qt

I am new to the world of qt and python. I have created vertical slider in pyqt4. I want to access the vertical slider(int) value and assign it to a variable since I have to pass value of this variable to another function. Here is my code please suggest me what should I add to my code so as to get value from slider.

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainwindow.ui'
#
# Created: Thu Sep 25 13:08:56 2014
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.9.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(698, 455)
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralWidget"))
        self.verticalSlider = QtGui.QSlider(self.centralWidget)
        self.verticalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 70, 19, 251))
        self.verticalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalSlider.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalSlider"))
        self.lcdNumber = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self.centralWidget)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 130, 211, 81))
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lcdNumber"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 698, 21))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuBar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mainToolBar"))
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusBar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.verticalSlider, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("valueChanged(int)")), self.lcdNumber.display)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have the following in your code:

```
sld = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Vertical, self)
```

You can connect the changes in the slider to an other function like:

```
sld.valueChanged[int].connect(self.funcThatTakeAnIntAsArg)
```

and define the method

```
def funcThatTakeAnIntAsArg(self, valueOfSlider):
    self.someWidget.doSomethingWith(valueOfSlider)
```

As the `QSlider` inherists `QAbstractSlider`, you can get the [value](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractslider.html#details) with `QSlider.value`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this,

```
self.verticalSlider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.func)
```

where func is defined as:

```
def func(self, value):
  print value
```